# Is there a PNaCl test module that devs can use to see if PNaCl is running?

Tags: google-chrome, google-nativeclient

One of our partners makes an app that uses the Chrome Portable Native Client plugin, PNaCl for short.  We use this app on our website, and some of our users have problems loading it, and I think that in many cases it is because PNaCl is being blocked from running for some reason (or maybe isn't installed properly).

What would be really ideal is if I could run some super-minimal PNaCl app that just does something very basic, like adding a class to the parent page body, and stops, on the page BEFORE we send people off to our partner's app.  Then, I can wait a short while and test (with javascript) if the body has that class, and if it doesn't, assume there's some PNaCl problem and highlight that to the user, with some helpful info etc.

I know **zero** about writing PNaCl apps, and so this might turn into a bit of an annoying diversion from my actual job.  But, it occurred to me that I'm probably not the first person to have this problem, and that maybe someone else has done a very basic PNaCl app already that does something like this, which I could utilize.

So, questions:

- Does anyone know if there is a PNaCl app like this?
- Is there a repo of publically available PNaCl apps that I can browse?
- does it even work in this way, where I can just reuse someone else's app on my website?  Eg would I need to register it with Chrome or something?

Basically, any advice welcome... thanks!

Comment: You can only use PNaCL on Chrome Apps on Chrome OS. https://developer.chrome.com/native-client/migration https://groups.google.com/d/topic/native-client-discuss/Ld1QW1-EypU/discussion. You probably need to switch to [tag:webassembly].

Comment: @JoshLee are you confusing google's plans for deprecating PNaCl with the actual reality?  PNaCl apps run in Chrome on a variety of different OSs, including Mac, Windows, Linux etc.   I can't switch to web assembly because I'm trying to test whether a PNaCl app is going to work.  You could maybe suggest that the partner should implement their software in Wasm instead, and they are in fact doing that, but it's a totally different issue.

Comment: I'm on Chrome 76 Beta, and the demos at https://gonativeclient.appspot.com/demo/bullet will not load.

Comment: @JoshLee I understand what you mean, thanks.  So,  your previous comment about only using PNaCL on Chrome OS refers to Chrome 76 onwards?  Can the user do something to enable PNaCl?  Eg can you do anything in your chrome settings which will let you use those demos you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Chrome 76 PNaCl is available only as an origin trial (on its way to full removal from the open web in December 2019). See the [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/native-client-discuss/Ld1QW1-EypU) for more details.

Comment: What does that mean for a site already using a PNaCl app though?  Does it mean that from Chrome 76 the user is required to manually enable PNaCl or something like that?

Comment: No, an origin trial allows a particular site to enable the feature without making the user do anything. But the site author does need to sign up. Check out the origin trial doc: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/OriginTrials/blob/gh-pages/developer-guide.md